# Não consigo adicionar uma reference

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou a fazer um projeto para a escola em C#, com base de dados e MySQL. Quando tento adicionar a extensão **`Mysql.Data`** ela simplesmente não é adicionada.

Já instalei o MySQL Connector, já vi centenas de tutoriais mas quando adiciono a extensão como referência ela é marcada mas não é adicionada. Basta voltar a ir em **Add - Reference - Extensions** e ela não está marcada de novo.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Como você fez a instalação? Pode dizer qual é a versão do framework .NET do seu projeto?

Answer (score 1):

A versão da dll é incompatível com a versão do .Net Framework do seu projeto. Isso pode acontecer se você estiver tentando adicionar uma dll gerada na versão 4.0 do .Net framework em um projeto que usa a versão 2.0.